# Is it good idea to use Optional.of() method to make method chaining?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

Is it good idea to use Optional.of() method to make method chaining ?

i had a conversation with group of collegues about Optional.of() method.
  currently one of the project they are using Optional.of() method to 
  achieve the method chaining functional programming style .

Here i am giving the sample example :

```
    TxResponse initTxDataResponse = gateway.initiateTx(initTxDataRequest);
    Optional.of(initTxDataResponse)
            .map(initTxDataResponse::getReturnCode)
            .filter(code -> ResponseCode.SUCCESS.getCode().equals(code))
            .map(code -> {
                // doing some business logic ,we are not
                return code;
            }).orElseThrow(() -> new NoTransactionFound());
```

I feel we are overusing of the Optional.of() method

Is it good practice use the Optional.of() method to achieve functional programming style in jdk 8 ?

Case 2 :

```
TxResponse response = transactionRepository.getTransacationById(TransactionId).elseThrow(() -> ResourceNotFoundException());

Optional.of(response)
        .map(response::getReturnCode)
        .filter(code -> ResponseCode.SUCCESS.getCode().equals(code))
        .map(code -> {
            // doing some business logic ,we are not
            return code;
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException());
```

In this case Optional.of() is required to achieve functional programming style ?

Comment: No. That's not what it's for.

Comment: @JBNizet Can you please explain what is it for, then?

Comment: `Optional` was designed as a return value to indicate that value might be null (commonly used in `Stream` to process results).

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the usecases. What OP mentions is also another usecase, right? doing operations without care of null value?

Comment: https://youtu.be/fBYhtvY19xA?t=5m8s. @PankajSinghal yes, it's another use-case. A use-case that Optional was **not** designed for. https://youtu.be/fBYhtvY19xA?t=24m51s.

Comment: Optional.of() method accepts only non null value .for example if we pass null we are endup with again Null pointer Exception .

Comment: public static <T> Optional<T> of(T value)
Returns an Optional with the specified present non-null value.
Type Parameters:
T - the class of the value
Parameters:
value - the value to be present, which must be non-null
Returns:
an Optional with the value present
Throws:
NullPointerException - if value is null.

Comment: My opinion: It’s not the primary use of `Optional`, but I have seen a couple of compelling similar uses. If you are happy with your code, keep it, it’s not hard to read.

Comment: Paul Rooney ,Thanks for the suggestion . another case In another case : 

   TxResponse response = transactionRepository.getTransacationById(TransactionId).elseThrow(() -> ResourceNotFoundException());

 Optional.of(response)
            .map(initTxDataResponse::getReturnCode)
            .filter(code -> ResponseCode.SUCCESS.getCode().equals(code)).map(code -> {
                // doing some business logic ,we are not
                return code;
            }).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException());

Comment: Paul Rooney i have updated my question with case 2 in this case its not required Optional.of() ?

Answer (score 3):

If you don’t mind an answer without code, just my 0.02$.

We have been fighting over this at my work place (in code reviews) quite a lot. To be frank I am sometimes lost as to when it is correct (read intended by the creators of it) or not. I don’t even think that at the time of creation, Stuart Marks and the others were sure how this would be (ab)used. Like any other feature in the Java language, it will get abused, be sure of that. But over time, best practices will appear and people will use that.

I tend to be on the side that *iff* it does not hurt performance, your usage is OK. At least its sooo easy to read (speaking for myself here), compared to if else checks; but again it might be me doing (too) much Java-8 and above code.

That being said, it’s way too easy to turn it into a total mess, where that bound is, is up to you (and most probably your team).

Answer (score 2):

I think, Java `Optional` is made for these type of use cases only - To avoid null checks and do operations via chaining & without the fear of NPE.

I don't think you are overusing `Optional`.

From the [Official Article from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html)

> The purpose of *Optional* is not to replace every single null reference
>   in your codebase but rather to help design better APIs in which—just
>   by reading the signature of a method—users can tell whether to expect
>   an optional value. In addition, *Optional* forces you to actively unwrap
>   an *Optional* to deal with the absence of a value; as a result, you
>   protect your code against unintended null pointer exceptions.

Comment: Optional.of() method accepts only non null value .for example if we pass null we are endup with again Null pointer Exception .

Comment: what about in case 2 ?

Comment: @Madhu but Optional.ofNullable is also present

Answer (score 0):

If initTxDataResponse is nullable, then maybe it should be like this ?

```
Optional<TxResponse> initTxDataResponse = 
        gateway.initiateTx(initTxDataRequest);

response.map(....)
```

Comment: I believe that if `initTxDataResponse` would be nullable then, in case it would be null, `Optional.of(initTxDataResponse)` would throw a `NullPointerException`.