# using Optional to validate null when getting value from map

Tags: java-8, option-type

I have this line

```
List<Integer> someListWithLongName = someMapWithLongName.containsKey(someObjectWithLongName.get()) 
    ? someMapWithLongName.get(someObjectWithLongName.get()) 
    : Collections.emptyList();
```

That I wanted to change to make it a bit more readable, so I chose:

```
List<Integer> someListWithLongName = Optional.of(someMapWithLongName.get(someObjectWithLongName.get())
    .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
```

But I was told that the purpose of Optional is different. However, I'm failing to see why.
Is it really so? why?

Comment: [related IMO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52348334/1059372)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people will have different views on this but a good practice is to always use something the way it was intended.

[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53504573/is-using-optional-ofnullable-as-a-replacement-for-the-ternary-operator-a-good-pr/53504865#53504865) answer for consequences of misusing the `Optional<T>` type.

instead of your current solution, a better solution hinted by @JB Nizet would be using `Map::getOrDefault` available as of JDK8.

```
List<Integer> result = map.getOrDefault(key, Collections.emptyList());
```