# JDK 8 Optional Features

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Am sorry, if am not clear :
I am working on implementing Restful Services using Spring Boot.
I am building a URI based on the request parameters. I am checking for the parameter values and based on that I need to build the URI using the parameter values. If it is NOT null I want to add it to the URI parameter.
*host*/hello?abc="somevalue"

```
   MultiValueMap<String,String> params=new LinkedMultiValueMap<String,String>();
   if (null != abc) {
       params.add("abc","123");
   }
```

I am new to JDK 8 features.

1) How can I do this using JDK 8 optional features?

2) Is it possible both to throw an exception and log it using Optional?

Comment: it's not clear what you are looking for , but for null check you can use `Objects.isNull(Object obj)`

Comment: No, with Optional it is not possible “to throw an exception and log it”, but neither does your code example.

Comment: With `Optional` it’s easy and straightforward to throw an exception in case of the value missing, if this was what you meant? I agree that it’s very unclear. And then leave to whatever code catches it whether to log it or what should be done.

Comment: I don't know what you are looking for ,if you want to check your value is null,please use `null != value`

Comment: see the accepted answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53504573/is-using-optional-ofnullable-as-a-replacement-for-the-ternary-operator-a-good-pr) it provides some good advice as to when you should or should not use Optional and this is certainly not the case to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I frankly see no point in using an `Optional` here. The code you have is fine (we can always discuss the Yoda condition).

If you insist, you may write:

```
    Optional.ofNullable(abc).ifPresent(abc -> params.add("abc","123"));
```

Link: [Yoda Conditions: To Yoda or Not to Yoda](http://knowthecode.io/yoda-conditions-yoda-not-yoda)

Comment: "I frankly see no point in using an Optional here." couldn't agree more. 1+. that's pretty much as good as it gets.

Comment: @Ole V V Thank You.