# orElseThrow of optional object can not be resolved

Tags: java, android, java-8, option-type

I am quite new to the concept of Optional. In the code posted below, i am checking the following:

```
if (operation_1) {

    if (operation_2) {

        if (operation_3) {

        } else {
            throw_3
        }
    } else {
        throw_2
    }
} else {
    throw_1
}
```

but for this code, android studio, generates an error for the second orElseThrow() operation "marked below".
please let me why I receive this error?how to fix it? whether or not the code i wrote below satisfies the conditions shown above.

**code**:

```
OptionalsUtils.toOptional(Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), MovieDatabase.class, ActMain.DATA_BASE_NAME))//operation_1
            .map(x->{
                MovieDatabase movieRoomDb = x.fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
                this.setInitializedBuiltMovieRoomDatabase(movieRoomDb);
                return movieRoomDb;
            })//operation_2
            .map(y->{
                SupportSQLiteOpenHelper openHelperInstance = y.getOpenHelper();
                this.setSQLOpenHelperInstance(openHelperInstance);
                return openHelperInstance;
            })//operation_3
            .orElseThrow(()-> new NullPointerException(THROW_SQL_OPEN_HELPER_NULL))//throw_3
            .orElseThrow(()-> new NullPointerException(THROW_ROOM_DATABASE_PERSISTENT_BUILD_NULL))//throw_2<-cases error
            .orElseThrow(()-> new NullPointerException(THROW_ROOM_DATABASE_PERSISTENT_BUILDER_NULL));//throw_1
```

Comment: What does `OptionalsUtils.toOptional(…)` do?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using an Optional here as it's not meant to
replace simple "if" cases.

instead, invert the `if` conditions to remove the nesting:

```
if (!operation_1) 
   throw_1;
if(!operation_2)
   throw_2;
if(! operation_3)
   trow_3;

...  
...
```

---

As for your code, you cannot just chain `orElseThrow` methods as shown because the first call to `orElseThrow` will return the value encapsulated within the Optional if present otherwise throws the supplied exception thus the result of this method call is no longer an `Optional`.

Comment: thanks, but would you please tell me why optional in this case should not replace if-statements?

Comment: @user10776303 see the accepted [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53504573/is-using-optional-ofnullable-as-a-replacement-for-the-ternary-operator-a-good-pr)