# What's the advantage of Optional.ofNullable(itemKey) over itemKey == null

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I was just wondering when do we need to choose Optional over `if else` or nested `null` check. say for example is there any advantage of one another below or do you think the Optional could be an overkill

```
String.valueOf(Optional.ofNullable(itemKey).map(ItemKey::getId).orElse(null));
```

vs

```
String.valueOf(itemKey == null ? null : itemKey.getId());
```

I always keen to use the `Optional.of` or `Optional.ofNullable` when I had to pick nested item of a given object like below,

```
private String formatCurrency(String symbol, BigDecimal value) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(value)
            .map(BigDecimal::doubleValue)
            .map(Object::toString)
            .map(val -> symbol + val.replaceAll(REGEX_REMOVE_TRAILING_ZEROS, "$2"))
            .orElse("");
}
```

Can I please know where in the code the Optional is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: here is [my take](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52348334/1059372) on it

Comment: `return value == null? "": symbol + value.toString().replaceAll( REGEX_REMOVE_TRAILING_ZEROS, "$2")` compared to your `Optional` variant… decide yourself, what is more readable (the boxing to `Double` is unnecessary in either case).

Comment: I think it's better to use String.valueOf(itemKey == null ? null : itemKey.getId()), because the code is more readable. The main advantage of Optional is to avoid null values, declaring clearly that a variable may not be present. So I don't see any advantage in using an Optional.ofNullable().orElse(null), it's just a more complex syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have itemKey in your code, there is no meaning of transforming it to an Optional, it just makes the code more complex. However, if you want to use optionals, I think it'd be more appropriate to do something like this:

```
public Optional<ItemKey> getItemKey() {
    if (...) {
        return Optional.of(new ItemKey());
    }
    return Optional.empty()
}

public void mainCode() {
    String id = getItemKey().map(ItemKey::getId).orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @robertobatts that make me feel the Optionals are best suited for return values and it clearly represents the object may or may not present.